# To be leaning as motion or state?

Tags: present-continuous

I was wondering, when you say "He was leaning/leaning over", does it describe the state of being inclined or the motion of becoming inclined?

For example,"He was leaning over but I stopped him"?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is *yes*.  In other words, it could mean either. Especially if you include *over*, it can mean the act of leaning, which means leaning more and more (a greater angle).

Comment: thank yoy!So both "to be leaning/to be leaning over" could refer to the motion, but "over" emphasize the motion better? Am I right??

Comment: Yes, I think so.